# Stored Procedure Inserts Data Just Once

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have been trying to create a stored procedure to fill up a calendar table using the customers valid from and valid to dates. To map them to their respective records, they are tied down with a foreign key in the calendar table.

Now, the stored procedure is called right after they successfully sign up and their record is created. However, the stored procedure runs successfully only once. No records for subsequent clients is created after it has run the first time.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `fillGroomerCalendar`(IN `dateStart` DATE, IN `dateEnd` DATE, IN `groomerID` INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE adate date;
    START TRANSACTION;
    WHILE dateStart <= dateEnd DO
        SET adate = (SELECT groomerDate FROM groomer_calendar WHERE groomerDate = dateStart);
        IF adate IS NULL THEN BEGIN
            INSERT INTO groomer_calendar (groomerID, groomerDate, groomerDateStatus) VALUES (groomerID, dateStart, "Open");
        END; END IF;
        SET dateStart = date_add(dateStart, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END WHILE;
    COMMIT;
END
```

Any help understanding why this fails after the first successful run is appreciated.

P.S.: I have checked if there are locks on the table that's causing the next runs to be blocked. But no tables are locked.

**UPDATED:**

In line with Nick's comment and his answer posted below, this is the corrected procedure code. This may help others find the solution, should they face a similar problem.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `fillGroomerCalendar`
    (IN `dateStart` DATE, IN `dateEnd` DATE, IN `inGroomerID` INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE adate date;
    START TRANSACTION;
    WHILE dateStart <= dateEnd DO
        SET adate = (SELECT groomerDate FROM groomer_calendar 
            WHERE groomerDate = dateStart AND groomerID = inGroomerID);
        IF adate IS NULL THEN BEGIN
            INSERT INTO groomer_calendar (groomerID, groomerDate, groomerDateStatus) 
                VALUES (inGroomerID, dateStart, "Open");
        END; END IF;
        SET dateStart = date_add(dateStart, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END WHILE;
    COMMIT;
END
```

Comment: I suspect `SELECT groomerDate FROM groomer_calendar WHERE groomerDate = dateStart` should be `SELECT groomerDate FROM groomer_calendar WHERE groomerDate = dateStart AND groomerID = in_groomerID` (note you need to change the name of the input variable to avoid a name clash)

Comment: @Nick, forgive my language, but HOLY CRAP!!!!! That did it. If you can post your comment as an answer, I will be glad to accept it. This has saved me some time for sure. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're not checking the dates in the table against the specific `groomerID` value, so when you next run the procedure with similar dates `adate` is not `NULL` because of the previous inserts. So you need to add a test for `groomerID` to the `SELECT` for `adate`. However then you have a second issue, because your column name matches your parameter name, so trying to use `WHERE groomerID = groomerID` will result in the same problem. You can change your parameter name to e.g. `in_groomerID` to work around that. So this should be your query:

```
SET adate = (SELECT groomerDate
             FROM groomer_calendar
             WHERE groomerDate = dateStart
               AND groomerID = in_groomerID);
```